# Get Class Reference from Class Type or String

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

So I've been looking around at a ton of similar questions but none of them seem to be attempting the same thing I am.  I need a reference to a class, not a class instance.

I am trying to dynamically make a class reference for a generic type function.  My function is as follows:

```
private void CleanupTable<T, U>(DbSet<T> dbSet, CleanupModel.Tables table, DbSet<U> lastDbSet, dynamic removedRec) where T : class where U : class
{
    ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression idProp = Expression.Property(tpe, typeof(T).GetProperty(GetIdProperty(lastDbSet)));
    Expression constIdProp = Expression.Constant(removedRec.GetType().GetProperty(GetIdProperty(lastDbSet)).GetValue(removedRec, null), typeof(int));
    Expression completeExpression = Expression.Equal(idProp, constIdProp);

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(completeExpression, tpe);
    List<T> removedRecs = dbSet.Where(expression).ToList();

    removedRecs.ForEach(rec =>
    {
        DbSet nextSet = GetNextSet(dbSet);

        //Here is where I'm trying to create a reference using nextSet
        CleanupTable</*nextSetType reference*/, T>(nextSet, GetNextTable(dbSet), dbSet, rec);

        dbSet.Remove(rec);
        reportHelper.ReportSuccess(table, ReportHelper.ReportReasons.Linked, rec);
    });
}
```

Here is the code for `GetNextSet()`:

```
private DbSet GetNextSet(CleanupModel.Tables table)
{
    switch (table)
    {
        case CleanupModel.Tables.Version: return context.Page;
        //More cases
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

I have tried using things like `GetType()` but the generic does not accept a `Type`.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: You can use [MakeGenericMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx). Check the example at the end

Comment: I'm not sure that's doing what I need it to.  Or maybe I don't understand it well enough.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Why is type inference not working? What is the signature of `GetNextSet`? What is the type of `nextSet`?

Comment: I added the code for `GetNextSet`.  I am returning a `DbSet<>` and in the first case in my code it is returning `DbSet<Page>` type and I want to put that `Page` reference into the generic function call

Comment: Then let type inference figure it out for you: `CleanupTable(nextSet, GetNextTable(dbSet), dbSet, rec);`. The compiler should be able to figure out by itselft `T` from the type of `nextSet` and `U` form the type of `dbSet`.

Comment: I think in order for that to work I would have to declare `nextSet` as a `DbSet<TEntity>` but the problem is I don't know the entity that `GetNextSet` is going to return.  It can't infer the types because `DbSet` is generic

Comment: Is there a way I could return a generic `DbSet<TEntity>` from `GetNextSet` and then figure out the type after it's been passed back?

Answer (score 0):

## **SOLUTION**

So I solved it thanks to the help of InBetween.  I ended up letting `CleanupTable()` infer the types from the arguments.  The problem originally was that it could not infer the type of `nextSet` because it was a generic `DbSet` type and was not implicitly typed.  I solved this issue by just setting the related values to dynamics and let `CleanupTable()` figure it out at run-time.

**Here's the updated code:**

*CleanupTable()*

```
private void CleanupTable<T, U>(DbSet<T> dbSet, CleanupModel.Tables table, DbSet<U> lastDbSet, dynamic removedRec) where T : class where U : class
{
    ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression idProp = Expression.Property(tpe, typeof(T).GetProperty(GetIdProperty(lastDbSet)));
    Expression constIdProp = Expression.Constant(removedRec.GetType().GetProperty(GetIdProperty(lastDbSet)).GetValue(removedRec, null), typeof(int));
    Expression completeExpression = Expression.Equal(idProp, constIdProp);

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(completeExpression, tpe);
    List<T> removedRecs = dbSet.Where(expression).ToList();

    removedRecs.ForEach(rec =>
    {
        dynamic nextSet = GetNextSet(table);
        if (nextSet == null)

        CleanupTable(nextSet, GetNextTable(table), dbSet, rec);

        dbSet.Remove(rec);
        reportHelper.ReportSuccess(table, ReportHelper.ReportReasons.Linked, rec);
    });
}
```

*GetNextSet()*

```
private dynamic GetNextSet(CleanupModel.Tables table)
{
    switch (table)
    {
        case CleanupModel.Tables.Version: return context.Page;
        //More cases

        default: return null;
    }
}
```